# how to concatenate the list elements into a string using forloop in C#

Tags: c#

I have `list` object and I want to make a message by concatenating the values. 
In `list` there are two properties called `area` and `filled`. I need such way that `model[0].area = model[0].filled and model[0].area = model[1].filled`. 
According to the condition array list object may be 0 to 5 elements

Example: `Area1 = 8.12` and `Area2 = 7.8` filled, data type filled - double , area = string

```
List<MHViewModel> model = getMHDetails();
model = model.Where(x => x.Filled > 8).ToList();

int numbers = model.Count;
string data = "";
if (numbers > 0)
{
    data = model[0].Area + model[0].Filled.ToString("0.00") ;
}
```

Comment: So, what did you try?

Comment: Cannot understand most of your requirements, but you can use Linq Aggregate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can keep using *Linq* and put `string.Join` to concat:

```
    var concat = string.Join(" and ", model
      .Select((item, index) => $"Area{index + 1}={item.Filled:F2}"));

    string result = string.IsNullOrEmpty(concat) ? "" : $"{concat} filled.";
```

If you insist on *for loop*:

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < model.Count; ++i) {
      if (sb.Length > 0)
        sb.Append(" and ");

      sb.Append($"Area{i + 1}={model[i].Filled:F2}"); 
    } 

    string result = sb.Length > 0 ? $"{sb.ToString()} filled." : "";
```

Comment: Area1=Kadma and Area2=Kadma and Area3=Kadma filled.getting like this.
i need Area1=22.3 and Area2=12.3 and Area3=6.7 filled.

Comment: @coder: Sorry, it seems I've put wrong property `item.Filled` should have been used (see my edit)

Comment: its working but i need only 2 digit after decimal in filled variable.Area1=4.57708 and  and Area3=7.53437 filled.im using the top snippet.

Comment: @coder: then add *format*, `F2` (two digits after decimal point) in your case - see my edit

Comment: thanks for ur valuable time and code.